# When substituting one ability for another on a skill check which kind of check does it qualify as?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, monk, unearthed-arcana, barbarian

The Unearthed Arcana Monk tradition [Way of the Astral Self](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-WildAstral.pdf) has the following ability (page 2 of the PDF):

> **Arms of the Astral Self**
>
> You can use your Wisdom modifier in place of your Strength modifier when making Strength checks and Strength saving throws.

Imagine such a monk took 1 level dip into Barbarian and picked up that class's rage ability which includes:

> You have advantage on all Strength checks and Strength saving throws.

If the monk goes to make a strength check (say, a grapple check), does the monk have advantage on the check because it counts as a strength check (but she's using her wisdom modifier)?

Or does she roll a normal check with her wisdom modifier because it's now a wisdom check, as determined by the fact that she's using wisdom for the check, not strength?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They would still get advantage.

The quote is quite clear:

> You can use your Wisdom modifier in place of your Strength modifier when making **Strength checks and Strength saving throws**.

In your example it is still a strength check but the character is using their Wisdom modifier. That doesn't change the nature of the check or, in game terms, the action they are performing.

The DM has called for a strength check and nothing in Arms of the Astral Self changes that.