# Can an Astral Self Monk/Stars Druid apply the dragon starry form to grapples?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, monk, multi-classing, grapple

> Arms of the Astral Self
>
> While the spectral arms are present, you gain the following benefits:
>
> You can use your Wisdom modifier in place of your Strength modifier when making Strength checks and Strength saving throws.

> Starry Form
>
> **Dragon.** A constellation of a wise dragon appears on you. When you make an Intelligence or a Wisdom check or a Constitution saving throw to maintain concentration on a spell, you can treat a roll of 9 or lower on the d20 as a 10.

Would the Strength check in grappling be considered a Wisdom check instead if you choose to replace your strength modifier with your wisdom modifier, thus qualifying it for Starry Form?

Comment: Regardless [this question has been asked before](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/162945), so after confirmation we'll mark it as a duplicate, which is not a bad thing by any means.

Comment: Oops, didn't see that this had been asked before. Also, sorry for missing the dnd-5e tag, added now.